# Varnish VCL - how can I examine req.backend_hint?

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl, varnish-4

I have the following VCL file:

```
vcl 4.0;

import std;
import directors;

backend one {
    .host = "localhost";
    .port = "3333";
}
backend two {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "3334";
}

sub vcl_init {
  new random_director = directors.random();
  random_director.add_backend(one, 10);  # 2/3 to backend one
  random_director.add_backend(two, 5);   # 1/3 to backend two
}

sub vcl_recv {
    set req.backend_hint = random_director.backend();
    std.log(req.backend_hint.host);
}
```

The concept is that I want to re-write the req.url after randomly assigning the user to a backend.

So when a new user arrives, they will be randomly assigned to a backend.  Then I will add some logic with an if statement to re-write the URL path one way if they are assigned to backed one, and another way if they are assigned to backend two.

My problem is that after the line

```
set req.backend_hint = random_director.backend();
```

I can't figure out which backend the user got assigned to.  In other words, I don't know how to examine req.backend_hint.

I tried to use

std.log(req.backend_hint.host);

but that throws a compilation error (not a STRING_LIST).

The example I have above is adapted from here: http://book.varnish-software.com/4.0/chapters/Saving_a_Request.html

So, my question is: how can I inspect req.backend_hint?

Comment: Can't you just `std.log(req.backend_hint);`?